# Given an array of integers, swap the elements in pairs ? what's wrong with my code I am getting the answer right but not able to submit

Tags: python, swap

[picture of my code, where I get the answer right but something is wrong that's why I am not able to submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV72E.png)

n= int(input())

a=list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]

li=[]
length=(len(a))

for i in range(1,length,2):

```
    q=(a[i])
    w=a[i-1]
    li.append(q)
    li.append(w)
```

if n%2 !=0:

```
li.append(a[-1])

print(*li,end=' ')
```

else:

```
print(*li,end=' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of text/code. Rather please edit your question to inline the text. Also, please use a more concise title and explain your question in your post. Suggested reading: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("Enter number in list")
l=list(map(int,input().split()))

print("List is",l)
i=0
while(i<len(l)):
    l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
    i+=2

print("Outcome : ",l)
```

[image]

The better approach:-

```
def swap(list1):
    n = 2 if len(list1)%2 == 0 else 3
    for i in range(0,len(list1),n):
        list1[i],list1[i+1] = list1[i+1], list1[i] 
    return list1
listr = [1,2,3,4]
print(listr)
print(swap(listr))
```

[image]

To Handle for odd and even length-

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7]
n = len(lst)
print(lst)
for i in range(0,n-1,2):
    lst[i],lst[i+1] = lst[i+1],lst[i]
print(lst)
```

[image]

Comment: these both method work for even no. in list elements, but not for odd

Comment: https://workat.tech/problem-solving/practice/swap-adjacent

Comment: this is the problem i trying to solve

Comment: @PrinceVerma check the recent update